# Not able to arrange two divs side by side

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, box-sizing

Okay, so I know there are a few questions similar to this on StackOverflow which already have been answered but they didn't help me.

I am building a messaging service and for that I have two divs, `contacts_box` (300px) and `message_box`(500px). They are both wrapped inside a parent `div` which is `800px` in `width`. I want `align` these two `divs` side by side inside the parent `div`. But no matter what I do, I just can't get them to align!

Please take a look at my HTML and CSS and show where I am going wrong with this?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.page_layout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.page_container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
// Contacts Box and its elements  
.contacts_box {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:300px;
    border:1px dashed magenta;
}
// Message Box and its elements
.message_box {
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    width:500px;
    border:1px dashed lemonchiffon;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kinskeep.com/test.css">
  </head>
<body>
<div class="page_layout">
  <div class="page_container">
    <div class="contacts_box"> CONTACTS BOX </div>
    <div class="message_box">
      <div class="message_displayBox"> Message Box </div>
      <div class="message_textBox"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use **float : left** property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `box-sizing` to solve the issue rather than calculating the width and border widths:

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to the inner containers and `box-sizing: content-box` to the outer container and there you go!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page_layout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.page_container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
 .contacts_box {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px dashed magenta;
}
 .message_box {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px dashed lemonchiffon;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page_layout">
    <div class="page_container">
      <div class="contacts_box">
        CONTACTS BOX
      </div>

      <div class="message_box">
        <div class="message_displayBox">
          Message Box
        </div>

        <div class="message_textBox">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The most basic solution: The border of the divs is not included in the width. So you either need to calculate the width as

```
width1 + border1 + width2 + border2 = 800px
```

or make your container div larger.

Comment: why not use `box-sizing: border-box`?

Answer (score 1):

Put your comments inside `/* Comments Goes Here */`

change your width `px` to `%` and use `box-sizing: border-box;` to the floated divs.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.page_layout
{
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid green;
}

.page_container
{
  width:800px;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear:both;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.contacts_box
{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:40%;
  border:1px dashed magenta;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.message_box
{
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  width:60%;
  border:1px dashed lemonchiffon;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_layout">
    <div class="page_container">
        <div class="contacts_box">
            CONTACTS BOX
        </div>
        <div class="message_box">
            <div class="message_displayBox">
                Message Box
            </div>
            <div class="message_textBox">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**
You have borders in both elements (`.contact_box` and `.message_box`) and they are taking 1px from each side so they will never fit together because there is not enough space, I recommend you to use the property `box-sizing:border-box;` for this cases, it'll put the borders inset of the element instead of outside, so you don't have to worry about them.

```
.contacts_box
{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:300px;
  border:1px dashed magenta;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.message_box
{
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  width:500px;
  border:1px dashed lemonchiffon;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Also if you are using pure css (without pre-processors) use comments like this `/* Comment */` to avoid problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. I did not consider the border-box property.

Comment: Yes @ShahQuadri It's a great property to implement when you don't want to worry about dynamic sizes.

Comment: it's better if you set `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` fyi

Answer (score 0):

Your comment method was wrong. 
in Vanilla CSS - we use `/* Your comment */`
to make comments.

`//` - is supported in LESS, SASS, Stylus kind of pre-processors.

---

**If you run your code on browser, you can see, none of the CSS for contactbox and messagebox was working.**

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.page_layout
{
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid green;
}

.page_container
{
  width:800px;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear:both;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

/* Contacts Box and its elements */

.contacts_box
{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:300px;
  border:1px dashed magenta;
}

/* Message Box and its elements */

.message_box
{
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  width:500px;
  border:1px dashed lemonchiffon;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kinskeep.com/test.css">
  </head>  
  
  <body>
    <div class="page_layout">
    <div class="page_container">
     <div class="contacts_box">
      CONTACTS BOX
     </div>
    
     <div class="message_box">
      <div class="message_displayBox">
       Message Box
      </div>
      
      <div class="message_textBox">
      </div>
      
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You give border to inner **DIV** so its also add in its actual width. So if possible give color to inner **DIV** or expand **Parent DIV** width.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.page_layout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.page_container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.contacts_box {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
.message_box {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kinskeep.com/test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page_layout">
    <div class="page_container">
      <div class="contacts_box">
        CONTACTS BOX
      </div>

      <div class="message_box">
        <div class="message_displayBox">
          Message Box
        </div>

        <div class="message_textBox">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE:** 
Your code is correct but you give wrong comment in CSS. That's why its not working. Please check comment in CSS part. Here I update your code with remove comment. Its working fine.

**UPDATE**

Also you can using **box-size:border-box** outer DIV  and **box-size:content-box** to inner DIV. You can solve it using this method also.

Answer (score 0):

We have to stop using floats and start using flex!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page_layout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.page_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.contacts_box {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  border: 1px dashed magenta;
}

.message_box {
  flex: 1 0 500px;
  border-left: 1px dashed lemonchiffon;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_layout">
  <div class="page_container">
    <div class="contacts_box">
      CONTACTS BOX
    </div>

    <div class="message_box">
      <div class="message_displayBox">
        Message Box
      </div>

      <div class="message_textBox">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your container with width:300px and border:1px as a whole has 301px width. Try changing your width to 299px or making 802px the bigger box

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kinskeep.com/test.css">
  </head>  
  <style>
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.page_layout
{
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid green;
}

.page_container
{
  width:800px;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear:both;
  border:1px solid blue;
}



.contacts_box {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 298px;
     border: 1px dashed magenta;
}


.message_box {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 498px;
     border: 1px dashed lemonchiffon; 
}
</style>
  <body>
    <div class="page_layout">
    <div class="page_container">
     <div class="contacts_box">
      CONTACTS BOX
     </div>
     <div class="message_box">
      <div class="message_displayBox">
         Message Box
      </div>
      <div class="message_textBox">
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </body>
</html>
</html>
```

if want to add border then reduce width by same px which you are taking borders
like make them 498 and 298 px res.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <style>

.page_layout
{
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid green;

}

.page_container
{
  width:800px;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear:both;
  border:1px solid green;
}

#contacts_box
{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:300px !important;
  background-color:#f9dada !important;
}


#message_box
{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:500px;
  background-color:#deffe5;
}
</style>
  </head>  
  
  <body>
    <div class="page_layout">
    <div class="page_container">
     <div id="contacts_box">
      CONTACTS BOX
     </div>
    
     <div id="message_box">
      Message Box
      
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are using `!important`?